# Bash shell script -- split string INCLUDING the delimeter?

Tags: bash, shell

I'm wondering if there's a simple way to split a string into an array and INCLUDE the delimeter?

For example:

```
foo = "a;b;c;d;"
```

Would parse to:

```
"a;" "b;" "c;" "d;"
```

It seems most functions strip out the delimeter.

Edit:  I need to end up not with echoed output but an array that I can then manipulate later in the script.  Also, it's probably easiest if the string can be read from a text file.

Comment: `foo = "something"` is already invalid. In contrast to most other languages, blanks aren't supported around the assignment operator. Both must be removed.

Comment: Would it be a problem simply to append the delimiter to the end of the item? (in case you know how to split excluding the delimiter)

Comment: Yes, sorry, foo="something" would be the right syntax.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare -a Array=($(echo 'a;b;c;' |cut -d';' --output-delimiter="; " -f1-))
echo ${Array[2]}
> c;
declare -a Array=($(echo 'a;b;c' |cut -d';' --output-delimiter="; " -f1-))
echo ${Array[2]}
> c
```

That's pretty gross, but hey, it kind of works. You'll need a different delimiter if you have spaces in your input, so this is not ideal.

Comment: will break if there is any whitespace in the data

Comment: indeed. that's precisely why I said it was gross and needed a different delimiter to support whitespace...

Comment: This is working exactly as I need (ugly's fine)...can it be modified to read the input string from a file?  If I just change "echo "a;b;c;" to "cat somefile.txt" will that work?

Answer (score 2):

```
foo="a;b;c;d;"
for z in $(echo $foo | sed -r 's/([^;]+;)/\1 /g') 
do
  echo $z
done

a;
b;
c;
d;
```

(After edit)
How to make an array:

```
# declare -a arr
arr=($(echo $foo | sed -r 's/([^;]+;)/\1 /g'))
```

Note: As Glenn pointed out, it will fail, if blanks build part of the content.

My handbook says, that I should use `declare -a` to declare an array, but in praxis it seems, I don't need it.

Comment: will break if there is any whitespace in the data.

Answer (score 1):

```
foo='foo bar;abc def;ghi;jlk;'
oldIFS="$IFS"
IFS=\;
declare -a ary=($foo)
for ((i=0; i<${#ary[@]}; i++)); do ary[$i]="${ary[$i]}$IFS"; done
IFS="$oldIFS"
echo "${ary[1]}"  # ==> "abd def;"
```

Comment: I've heard that it's kind of iffy to modify the IFS value, no?

Comment: @Dave: `IFS` is perfect for splitting a string on a given delimiter.  Just make sure to restore it to its original value at the end of what you're doing.

Comment: @Dave it is iffy if you don't pay attention to restoring it. Do it in a subshell (like `{ here }`) and you'll be safe

Comment: @sehe, a subshell is `( this )` -- `{ this; }` is in the current shell.

Comment: @glenn: good point, only half true; it _can_ be in the current shell. With my usage of it, it just never was :) but you taught me not to rely on that in the future

Comment: @sehe, your experience seems to contradict the bash man page (Compound Commands section)

Comment: @glenn: try `echo $BASHPID; { echo "in:$BASHPID"; } | { echo "pipe:$BASHPID"; cat; }` - it will return 3 distinct pids

Comment: @sehe, that's because you introduced a pipeline into the mix: from the man page, "Each command in a pipeline is executed as a separate process (i.e., in a subshell)" -- same effect without the first set of braces.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby(1.9+)

```
$ array=( $(echo "a;b;c;d;" | ruby -e 'gets.chomp.scan(/(\w;)/).each{|x|print "%s " % x}') )
$ echo ${array[0]}
a;
$ echo ${array[1]}
b;
$ echo ${array[2]}
c;
$ echo ${array[3]}
d;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may change the IFS value inside a function so that the IFS value outside that function remains unchanged.

And you can append a string to every array element without looping as well.

```
(
printf '%q\n' "$IFS"
splitButKeepDelim() {
  declare IFS="$1"    # limit scope of IFS
  array=( ${2} )      # hardcoded array name
  IFS=""
  array=( "${array[@]/%/;}" )  # append a ';' to every array item
  return 0
}
unset array
splitButKeepDelim ';' 'a;b;c;d;'
printf '%s\n' "${array[@]}"
printf '%q\n' "$IFS"
)
```